# Blocked updates: react router and redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Router [docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/redux.md#blocked-updates) have some info when to use `withRouter` with redux. However, I find them not entirely clear.

For example docs say to use `withRouter` when

> 1. The component is connected to redux via connect()(Comp).
> 2. The component is not a "route component", meaning it is not rendered like so:

Some things that weren't clear to me are:

- First of all are 1st and 2nd points above connected with AND? e.g. does component not update when 1st AND 2nd happen? (or is it an OR?)
- In the first case does it mean when I have `connect(mapStateToProps)(Comp)` it is fine to not use `withRouter`?
- The second point is unclear to me totally. Does it mean we should apply `withRouter` to ANY component (`connect`-ed or not?) which is not a "route component"?

---

<sub>Update: After some [exploration](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6635) it seems this should not be an issue in router 4.4 version anymore.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

> In the first case does it mean when I have connect(mapStateToProps)(Comp) it is fine to not use withRouter?

`connect()(Comp)` designates that it is connected component, it doesn't mean that `withRouter` may be unnecessary with other `connect` arguments like `connect(mapStateToProps)(Comp)`. [The documentation](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/redux.md#blocked-updates) mentions this as well:

```
// before
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Something)

// after
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(Something))
```

> Does it mean we should apply withRouter to ANY component (connect-ed or not?) which is not a "route component"?

We should apply `withRouter` to a component if it is not route component and we expect it to be updated when location is updated, i.e. it uses [route props](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props) in some way. A popular example is navigation menu where active item is highlighted, it's not a route component yet it needs to be aware of current route.

> Or why not attach withRouter to ANY connected component, will not it cover all cases?

This will provide unnecessary updates on router events for components that possibly don't need them because they don't use route props.

Comment: Do you know if in the link I posted in question, the docs actually imply that a component might not get updated if 1 AND 2 happen? (or is it an OR, 1 OR 2?). It is a bit unclear from the way it is written.

Comment: ok, for some reason I have a suspicion now the docs implied that component might not re render if both 1 AND 2 happen.

Comment: I double checked what the document says, and it doesn't make much sense, I honestly fail to understand the situation it describes. To my knowledge, regular and connected components will behave the same way with `withRouter` and <Route component>`, so it's unclear why they emphasized connected components at all. If a component receives route props, it will updated. If it doesn't, it won't. Sorry if my explanation was confusing. I edited the answer a bit to be clearer.

Comment: I'd suggest to open an issue in https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues regarding this document to clarify that. If there's specific situation they describe with *an app can have a component that doesn't update when the location changes <...> The problem is that Redux implements shouldComponentUpdate and there's no indication that anything has changed if it isn't receiving props* it would be great to see the example in docs.  I agree that it's even unclear if that's AND or OR that is supposed to be between '1' and '2' because they cannot be deduced from the situation they describe

Comment: I got some answer, FYI: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6439. If you want feel free to update your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I don't think that the answer needs to be updated. I still have no idea why it was necessary to mention this in Redux docs. The situation with `withRouter` applies to *any* component  that needs to be updated on route change, not just a component that was connected to Redux store.

Comment: Legend! Fixed a bug for me too!